# Parsing text in complex format to python data table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I have a txt file as like this

```
 Station coordinates and velocities:
  ----------------------------------
  Reference epoch: 2017-01-02 12:00:00

  Station name          Typ   A priori value  Estimated value    Correction     RMS error      3-D ellipsoid        2-D ellipse
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  CHNG 99128            X     -3233224.72062   -3233224.72062       0.00000       0.00120
                        Y      4067916.18933    4067916.18933       0.00000       0.00118
                        Z      3686212.02917    3686212.02917       0.00000       0.00091

                        U           61.78989         61.78989       0.00000       0.00160     0.00161    7.0
                        N         35.5333100       35.5333100       0.00000       0.00046     0.00044    1.8     0.00046    3.2
                        E        128.4780652      128.4780652       0.00000       0.00095     0.00094   -5.4     0.00095

  CHSG 98109            X     -3237146.18442   -3237146.18442       0.00000       0.00119
                        Y      3989513.50556    3989513.50556       0.00000       0.00130
                        Z      3767338.46367    3767338.46367       0.00000       0.00096

                        U          250.04930        250.04930       0.00000       0.00170     0.00170    5.4
                        N         36.4356270       36.4356270       0.00001       0.00048     0.00045    0.6     0.00048    0.6
                        E        129.0563506      129.0563506       0.00000       0.00095     0.00095    0.0     0.00095

  CHWN 09131            X     -3260411.69912   -3260411.69912       0.00000       0.00127
                        Y      4070678.22490    4070678.22490       0.00000       0.00143
                        Z      3659345.19301    3659345.19301       0.00000       0.00103

                        U           88.37577         88.37577       0.00000       0.00187     0.00188    5.0
                        N         35.2361197       35.2361197       0.00000       0.00048     0.00046    0.5     0.00048    0.3
                        E        128.6929994      128.6929994       0.00000       0.00098     0.00098   -0.6     0.00098
```

But I really Don't Know how can I change this one to python dataframe

especially station name isn't fill all cells so it make a problem

Could you help me with a solution please?

Comment: If this is not a html or xml file, `beautifoulsoup` is irrelevant. Hint: this is a fixed lenght fields file. You should 1/ read it line by line 2/ skip the headers 3/ use indices of fields in line to extract fields 4/ copy station name from previous line if empty. Try to write some code using these hints and and feel free to ask here it you get stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code uses [Pandas.read_fwf()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.read_fwf.html) to read the file by position, skips the first 6 rows, remove the blank lines and fill the Station Name for the empty rows with [fill_na()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html):

```
cols = [(3,23),(24,30),(30,45),(46,62),(63,76),(77,90), (91,102), (103, 109), (110,121), (122,128)]
names = ['Station name','Typ', 'A priori value', 'Estimated value', 'Correction', 'RMS error', '3-D', 'ellipsoid', '2-D', 'ellipse']
df = pd.read_fwf('my_file_24.txt', header=None, colspecs = cols, names = names, skiprows = 6)
df = df[~df.Typ.isnull()]
df['Station name'].fillna(method='ffill',inplace = True)
```

It generates the following Pandas data frame:

[image]